# PHP Looping through Soap response

Tags: php, xml, soap

How do I loop though this Soap response and echo the phone Number and status, I am new to soap response bit for json object am good

```
<AfricasTalkingResponse>
<SMSMessageData>
    <Message>Sent to 2/2 Total Cost: KES 1.6000</Message>
    <Recipients>
        <Recipient>
            <number>+254798834284</number>
            <cost>KES 0.8000</cost>
            <status>Success</status>
            <statusCode>101</statusCode>
            <messageId>ATXid_bbf2f1666edb884ebda0301ba6f3500f</messageId>
            <messageParts>1</messageParts>
        </Recipient>
        <Recipient>
            <number>+254719401837</number>
            <cost>KES 0.8000</cost>
            <status>Success</status>
            <statusCode>101</statusCode>
            <messageId>ATXid_e63021c301c9b82aebfe9acc972e49b9</messageId>
            <messageParts>1</messageParts>
        </Recipient>
    </Recipients>
</SMSMessageData>
```

Here is the code

```
    $curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.africastalking.com/version1/messaging",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"username\"\r\n\r\nFORB\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"to\"\r\n\r\n0719401837,0798834284\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"message\"\r\n\r\nTEst\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"from\"\r\n\r\nFORBES\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Postman-Token: 544432e2-000d-4dc7-af9c-d49c949c6a68",
        "apiKey: f2d6ca79d01dbfeee0a1ce42fb82d06d70b8f0ed4ac5f5fb44e11bdb578cd095",
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {


     /* echo $response;
<AfricasTalkingResponse>
    <SMSMessageData>
        <Message>Sent to 2/2 Total Cost: KES 1.6000</Message>
        <Recipients>
            <Recipient>
                <number>+254798834284</number>
                <cost>KES 0.8000</cost>
                <status>Success</status>
                <statusCode>101</statusCode>
                <messageId>ATXid_bbf2f1666edb884ebda0301ba6f3500f</messageId>
                <messageParts>1</messageParts>
            </Recipient>
            <Recipient>
                <number>+254719401837</number>
                <cost>KES 0.8000</cost>
                <status>Success</status>
                <statusCode>101</statusCode>
                <messageId>ATXid_e63021c301c9b82aebfe9acc972e49b9</messageId>
                <messageParts>1</messageParts>
            </Recipient>
        </Recipients>
    </SMSMessageData>
</AfricasTalkingResponse>

*/



    foreach($response->AfricasTalkingResponse->SMSMessageData->Recipients as $recipient){
        echo $recipient->status;
        echo $recipient->number;
    }
}
```

The response now is `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`  after trying to use the foreach that you have suggested. IT seems almost working just a small thing to edit and see. Thank in advance

here is the response

```
<AfricasTalkingResponse>
<SMSMessageData>
    <Message>Sent to 2/2 Total Cost: KES 1.6000</Message>
    <Recipients>
        <Recipient>
            <number>+254798834284</number>
            <cost>KES 0.8000</cost>
            <status>Success</status>
            <statusCode>101</statusCode>
            <messageId>ATXid_bbf2f1666edb884ebda0301ba6f3500f</messageId>
            <messageParts>1</messageParts>
        </Recipient>
        <Recipient>
            <number>+254719401837</number>
            <cost>KES 0.8000</cost>
            <status>Success</status>
            <statusCode>101</statusCode>
            <messageId>ATXid_e63021c301c9b82aebfe9acc972e49b9</messageId>
            <messageParts>1</messageParts>
        </Recipient>
    </Recipients>
</SMSMessageData>
```

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use simplexml to parse it as array  :

In SimpleXML, the object  is treated as the root element. So you can loop through the recipients items like so:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
foreach($xml->SMSMessageData->recipients as $recipient)
{
      echo (string)$recipient->status;
      echo (string)$recipient->number;
}
```

Comment: @Muhammed the error now is Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: which one do you try ?

Comment: I have the commented the response out

Comment: I see , it's not converted to array , so you need to use simpleXML